# Node not reading full contents of file

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I'm trying to get it to read & parse a json file to update it, but it's not reading the full file, it's stopping after a lot of the file and just not reading any more of it. It's a massive json file because I can't really store it as anything else, besides multiple json files.
[image]
The code of CacheManager is [here](https://github.com/FurryBotCo/E621Downloader.JS/blob/eb1e86ff61283ea62431f1a3bf42eb6d0557d33d/src/util/CacheManager.ts#L57)

The size of what it read is **143,360**, and the actual size of the file is **153,840**. I've never really ran into the issue, so I have no clue how to remedy it. I'm using `fs-extra` in the code, but I've verified that the same issue happens with the built-in `fs` module. I've printed out the content of what it got as well, so I can see that it is reading the file, and it is reading the right content, it's just not getting all of it. I'll link the [right content](https://pastebin.com/jTsDDEqu) and [what it's getting](https://pastebin.com/xL3q80yC). It's cut off at the end, you can see the part of the json for the md5. The code writing it to the file is just writing the raw content of the read file [here](https://butts-are.cool/2020-12-28_5-14-28.174.png) (look at the part below the first screenshot to see the regular code)

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the code section where you are reading the file and parsing the output?

Comment: look under the screenshot, there's a link to the github repo where the code is

Comment: links are not encouraged here on SO since they can become stale and hence could cripple your question for future readers.. The proper way is to include your code in the question.

Comment: have you tried https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra/blob/HEAD/docs/readJson-sync.md?

Comment: Seems to be working so far with readJsonSync, going to rewrite my code around that to make sure

Comment: Is the file changing often? How is the file created? Do you copy and paste the content?

Comment: The file is changing pretty often, yes, likely once every few seconds - The file is created when running the program - I copy and paste the content in when it moves the file because of failed parsing, but besides that all of the content was put in by the program itself earlier

Comment: It's downloading images from the internet, and writing to the file on every 10th download, the downloads typically take 2 seconds each *correction to the above comment, it's likely every 20 seconds or so

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is caused by the size of the file, you may look in some streaming parsing alternatives to standard JSON parse (like https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-json).

Note: I'll check and let you know

Edit for the reader: so far it seems some kind of race and SO caching, discussion in the comments.

Comment: The part that confuses me is that it only happens sometimes, and not every time

Comment: I've tried without issues also with standard JSON.parse and readFileSync.
Is there any process updating the file in the meanwhile?

Comment: there are worker threads happening here, I've tried moving all of the updating into the main process so they all send it there, yet it's not really queuing anything, they're still running as soon as it receives them

Comment: So then, it may happen that fs.writeFileSync in update method of CacheManager has finished writing, but SO is still updating the file. Try adding fs.fsyncSync(this.file) at the end of update method.

Comment: fsync takes a file descriptor (number), which I don't have since I'm using sync methods

Comment: You can obtain it, and writeFileSync should accept a file descriptor based on latest docs: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options

Comment: Looks to be working so far after adding the fsync bit, thanks

Comment: The only other reason that could come to my mind is another race: between threads, but you should have some mechanism of sync from what I have understood (messages to the main thread); between processes, but I think you don't have other processes writing the same file from what I have read so far.

Comment: I have ipc between threads and send the updates to the main thread so they're all processed in the same context & event loop, and in my theory one at a time, but apparently not